# Any difference when specifying the access modifier this way?

Tags: php, oop

I see a lot of people specify them like this.

```
protected $myVar;
protected $mySecondVar;
protected $myThirdVar;
```

But recently I found out you can specify them like this:

```
    protected $myVar, 
              $mySecondVar, 
              $myThirdVar;
```

Is there any difference in doing it this way, or is it simply a personal preference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function of both codes is exactly the same and you can't gain any measurable amount of performance improvement by either way. It is a matter of choice.

When you start using some API documentation tool (something like Apigen or Docblox), then the first way allows you to document each variable separately, the second way allows to add one comment to all three at once.

Answer (score 0):

personal preference i believe, but you can save some bytes if you choose the second way

Comment: Save what bytes?  In the source code?  That will hardly matter.  And if the source code is saved with spaces instead of tabs, you don't even save any bytes.

Comment: i didn't say it will matter if you choose the second way, i said is personal preference and save a couple of bytes if you don't write "protected" X times, so difficult to understand?

Answer (score 0):

+1 to *@user1031794* and usually it's easier to merge the first version if you use a revision control system and somebody changes one of the variables. (For example, if somebody adds a new `$myFourthVar` and another developer adds a new `$myFifthVar` variable at the same time.)